# Rigid body not falling down, floating away

Tags: animation, mesh, rigidbody

I wanted to make a bunch of these stars to fall into a bowl, sort of like cereal. I made the bowl and the plane passive objects and have tried different meshes (convex hull, mesh, cube…) and made the star an active one, calculated mass and when I pressed play it just fell through the bowl and the plane. I changed everything I could think of and then it started floating away, jumping from one place to another in just one frame.

here's the blender file if it helps
https://pasteall.org/blend/ccd9644ea2be40c595dc929b6b3248c0

this is the first frame:

[image]

this is the second frame, with the star already miles up:

[image]

Comment: Please provide blende file. Images should be pasted directly in the question, not in external sites.

Comment: Firstly ‘Apply Scale’ on each of your meshes. Then check the direction of your Normals on each of your meshes as this could be potentially affecting collision. Check that there are no other overlapping objects that are not visible (this could be a duplicate of your star that star that starts in the exact same location).

Comment: I’ve applied the scale and the normals are apparently ok, all are blue. Also no overlapping objects

Comment: My guess is that you've run into the problem where the body you meant to be falling starts inside the convex hull (or bounding box, depending) of the object you want it to fall into.  For both, check their Rigid Body -> Collision -> Shape setting and try Mesh rather than others.  If that's the problem the floating away will stop.

Comment: Changes all of them to mesh and now it’s going down but at the exact same rate, just falling through the bowl and the plane and jumping miles afar

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Thank you, I edited it

Comment: hello, we still can't see any picture, also maybe share your file? use https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots oh i submitted the pictures the way the previous comment said, i'mm clicking on them and they open fine for me, don't know what could be happening :/

Comment: please share your file, use the link I've given, once uploaded copy paste here the link (URL) it will give you

Comment: @moonboots added the file, thanks for all the help with the code and the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the *Scene panel > Rigid Body World > Settings >* bring back the *Speed* to 1
- Select the bowl, duplicate, remove the original (don’t know why), then in the *Physics > Rigid Body > Collisions > Shape*, choose *Mesh*, and a *Sensitivity > Margin* of 0
- For the cereal, choose *Shape > Convex Hull*

Comment: just did all that and nothing has changed :/ cereal keeps jumping way down. i was thinking my pc couldnt run a smooth animation but first time i tried the cereal fell and bounced as soon as it hit the bowl, so i know it can do that

edit: duplicated everything, deleted the originals and did what you said, seems to be working now. thank you SO much!!!!!!!!

Comment: yes there is something weird, I don't know why duplicating fixes the problem, maybe someone will tell

Comment: maybe it resets them somehow? would love to know why

Answer (score 3):

1. delete rigid body and collision for plane
2. change shape to mesh and margin to 0 for bowl
3. change speed in rigid body world to 1
4. cereal: shape to sphere, collision margin 0, run animation, shape to box, run animation, then shape to sphere again, run animation

result:

[image]

Comment: but 5, you arrived too late  ^^

Comment: looks like…..